# Battery usage info for longer than a day

Tags: android, adb, battery

I want to get battery usage data from my OnePlus 5 over a longer period (months), to keep track of how much I use my phone.

I've been playing around with adb and the batterystats dump, like so:

```
adb shell dumpsys batterystats > batterystats.txt
```

,but this data only seems to cover the data since the last charge.

Is battery usage data even stored for a longer period on your phone? Or is it reset every time you charge it? If it is stored somewhere, how would I access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39
Revision 3db08f2c6889-android
```

From the android documentation [dumpsys service](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/dumpsys.html). As indicated I executed the following command `adb shell dumpsys batterystats -h` to get the available arguments

From my experimentations, battery logs records do not last more than few days (in my case 10 days on my motorola Moto x 2nd gen). You may have to plug and log the phone more often than each month

As printed by the -h argument you can use enable `no-auto-reset` by doing `adb shell dumpsys batterystats enable no-auto-reset`

> no-auto-reset: don't automatically reset stats when unplugged

but you have to do it after each boot as indicated by the command

> Option state is not saved across boots.